# Geofire example to pull data from Firebase and populate markers on Google maps

Tags: angularfire, geofire

Can anyone point us to an example that pulls Geofire location data stored in Firebase and, not use the data to write to console.log, but use the data to populate markers on Google Maps.  We followed the documentation on line but couldn't even get the red circle to appear on Google map.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a full example on the [GeoFire for JavaScript GitHub repo](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/tree/master/examples#sfvehicles---fully-featured-example). The marker generation happens with [the `on("key_entered")` callback in `js/sfVehicles.js`](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/0d73d2d33be500723b0c2c01fe793ddd80d1fa82/examples/sfVehicles/js/sfVehicles.js#L33-L53).